# ASIFormDataRequest not called on Ad hoc build

Tags: ios, app-store, asihttprequest, adhoc

In my app I use ASIFormDataRequest to post and get data on the web. 
But when I build my app for the App Store (using ad-hoc build) some of these requests are simply not called! This ruins my app.

Does someone knows why? What is the difference between an build with Xcode and the app build for the App Store?

I call my request using :

```
 NSString *stringURL = @"http://myserv.com";
 NSURL *urlPosting = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

            __weak ASIFormDataRequest *requestFormBase1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urlPosting];


            [requestFormBase1 addPostValue:valueToPost forKey:@"key"];


            [requestFormBase1 startAsynchronous];

            [requestFormBase1 setCompletionBlock:^{

  ...
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Sample works for me.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("_downloadQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^(void){
    NSString *_apiURL = @"http://yours.com";
    __weak ASIFormDataRequest *formRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_apiURL]];
    [formRequest setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"response string : %@", [formRequest responseString]);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            //To execute the UIs.
        });
    }];
    [formRequest setFailedBlock:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            //To execute the UIs.
        });
    }];
    [formRequest startAsynchronous];
});
```

And in your code, may you need to change the execute process about " [requestFormBase1 startAsynchronous]; " to be last running, like this :

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://myserv.com";
NSURL *urlPosting = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
__weak ASIFormDataRequest *requestFormBase1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urlPosting];
[requestFormBase1 addPostValue:valueToPost forKey:@"key"];
[requestFormBase1 setCompletionBlock:^{ ... }];
[requestFormBase1 startAsynchronous];
```

This's the Block method running process standard. Hope it will help you.

Comment: yeap thank you very much, but i have desactivated optimization on ASIHTTPFormRequest and everything is fine, thank you very much Kuo

Comment: Welcome, hope you have a nice coding. :~D

Comment: :) hope so thank you Kuo, what do u use to replace ASIHTTPRequest now ?